# Selenium - json - c#

Tags: c#, json, selenium

```
var pre1 = driver.FindElementByTagName("pre").Text.Replace(@"\", "").Trim();
dynamic root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(pre1);
```

I have this JSON response:

```
{
"success": true,
"message": null,
"outright": false,
"eventId": 0,
"si": 111,
"leonard": [{
  "catalog":[0,0,0,0,0,0],
    "edit": 25965112,
    "mkilo": {
        "888;315;2;3;0": {
            "id": 1000,
            "description": "Car"
        },
        "888;316;2;4;0": {
            "id": 1001,
            "description": "Train"
        },
        "888;317;2;5;0": {
            "id": 1002,
            "description": "Airplane"
        }
    },
    "ti": "008000",
    "checkin": 254,
    "searchCar": {
        "id": 1000,
        "description": "Car"
    }
}],
"ti": 149498
```

}

**verified with jsonlint**

root.leonard[0].catalog.Count = 6 ---- > OK 
but 
root.leonard[0].mkilo.Count = null - -- Why?

I want to read the contents of `mkilo`.

Comment: I am a little unsure what your question is. It looks like maybe your problem is that mkilo is an object not a list. I would recommend defining a class for this response and avoiding `dynamic`. It might give you more information

Comment: mmm and how do I access the mkilo object?

Comment: I think you are accessing mkilo fine. It just does not have the structure you are expecting.

Comment: @0kkult0 - If possible could you post your original json here

Comment: this is the original

Comment: @0kkult0 - This JSON is not valid. check here https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I checked with jsonlint, it's valid

Comment: @0kkult0 - It would be awesome if you could [edit] your question and provide us with a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.  In this case that would be your code as well as the text of the JSON response as a raw string which we could caste into a console app and run for ourselves.

Comment: I edited the complete json file

Comment: @0kkult0 - can you show me what is pre1 contain ?

Comment: pre1 contains the json string I posted
https://dotnetfiddle.net/4O8LqG